# How to set the modification time of a file programmatically?

Tags: c, windows, file

How do I set the modification time of a file programmatically in Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows (or the standard CRT, anyhow) has the same [utimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wacf567.aspx) family of functions that UNIX has.

```
struct _utimebuf t;
t.tma = 1265140799;  // party like it's 1999
t.tmm = 1265140799;
_utime(fn, &t);
```

Using Win32 functions, [FILE_BASIC_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364217.aspx) can be set using [SetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365539.aspx).

```
FILE_BASIC_INFO b;
b.CreationTime.QuadPart = 1265140799;
b.LastAccessTime.QuadPart = 1265140799;
b.LastWriteTime.QuadPart = 1265140799;
b.ChangeTime.QuadPart = 1265140799;
b.FileAttributes = GetFileAttributes(fn);
SetFileInformationByHandle(h, FileBasicInfo, &b, sizeof(b));
```

Comment: as far as I understand _utime on windows does not work for directories, cause they are not treated as files on windows

Answer (score 19):

From: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/File/Modification_Time#C

```
#include <time.h>
#include <utime.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

const char *filename = "input.txt";

int main() {
  struct stat foo;
  time_t mtime;
  struct utimbuf new_times;

  stat(filename, &foo);
  mtime = foo.st_mtime; /* seconds since the epoch */

  new_times.actime = foo.st_atime; /* keep atime unchanged */
  new_times.modtime = time(NULL);    /* set mtime to current time */
  utime(filename, &new_times);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your mtime variable is unused, but otherwise a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365539(VS.85).aspx) with FileInformationType as FILE_BASIC_INFO

Comment: @bobbymcr, and actually trying to find the information and then code it themselves might be more beneficial than expecting someone else to do all the work.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be useful on windows [SetFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Darwin.
All security removed.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

// params
char *path = "a path to a dir, a file or a symlink";
long int modDate = 1199149200;
bool followLink = false;

// body
struct stat currentTimes;

struct timeval newTimes[2];

stat(path, &currentTimes);

newTimes[0].tv_sec = currentTimes.st_atimespec.tv_sec;
newTimes[0].tv_usec = (__darwin_suseconds_t)0;
newTimes[1].tv_sec = modDate;
newTimes[1].tv_usec = (__darwin_suseconds_t)0;

if (followLnk) {
    utimes(path, (const struct timeval *)&newTimes);
} else {
    lutimes(path, (const struct timeval *)&newTimes);
}
```