# How to detect if a file system supports nanoseconds precision in C?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I want to handle files in a single folder according to their modification time. But sometimes I get undefined behavior when the underlying file system doesn't support nanoseconds - so the files created in interval of 1 millisecond have the same modification time almost always. The rare exception occurs, if this 1 millisecond passes the 1 second boundary.

Is there a way to detect the support for nanoseconds in C?

Comment: You can try to set the mtime of a temporary file to something that will have a different value if there is no nanosecond precision. Then read back the mtime and compare it to your actual value.

Comment: @ThiefMaster as I described - it's a probabilistic method, since the file modification interval may pass the 1 second boundary - and give false-positive. I want an accurate method.

Comment: How is this probabilistic? It is a temporary file created by you that is only accessible by you. So you can set whatever mtime you want.

Comment: @abyss You can set the metime like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185338/how-to-set-the-modification-time-of-a-file-programmatically

Comment: @ThiefMaster sorry, misunderstood your point - I tried your method. And it seems the problem is somewhere else - my mtime is correct on both machines, while the mtime after open(O_CREAT|O_TRUNC) is not precise enough. I'm confused.

Comment: I would assume that by default file systems don't support nanosecond precision.

Comment: If order is important then you cannot rely on timestamp alone if you want portability.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck even timestamp in seconds is good enough for me, but the problem is in testing my code - since I rely on a natural mtime after creating the files in my tests. It's my final goal, but the question stays on its own - I hope there is some cool system call.

Comment: If you don't find a better way, you can always set mtime programmatically as a workaround.